# Insert a 2 bases de datos al mismo tiempo, uno en la nube y el otro local - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto lo cual se manejará de modo local, pero tiene que replicarse a la base de datos que está en la nube, estoy utilizando CodeIgniter, y la verdad no se como lo podria hacer

Les dejo lo que tengo planeado hacer.

Esta seria la configuracion de la base de datos:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'intranet',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['nube'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'username' => 'intranet',
    'password' => 'MY_SECRET_PASSWORD',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'database' => 'intranet',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Esto seria mi modelo :

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db_caja = $this->load->database('caja','default', TRUE);
}

function insertar_pago() {
    $sql = $this->_obtener_data_query_pagos();
    $query = $this->db_caja->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es bastante fácil, solo debes definir un objeto para trabajar cada base de datos, de la siguiente forma:

```
class Modelo extends CI_Model {

    // Creamos dos variables privadas, cada una para diferenciar nuestras
    // respectivas bases de datos
    private $BASE_DE_DATOS_LOCAL; // Base de datos local
    private $BASE_DE_DATOS_NUBE;  // Base de datos en la nube

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Inicializamos nuestro objeto de la base de datos local
        $this->BASE_DE_DATOS_LOCAL = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        // Inicializamos nuestro objeto de la base de datos en la nube
        $this->BASE_DE_DATOS_NUBE = $this->load->database('nube', TRUE)

    }

    function insertar_pago() {
        // Obtienes tu código SQL ...
        $sql = $this->_obtener_data_query_pagos();

        // Ejecutamos nuestro query en la base de datos local
        $query_local = $this->BASE_DE_DATOS_LOCAL->query($sql);

        // Ejecutamos nuestro query en la nube
        $query_nube = $this->BASE_DE_DATOS_NUBE->query($sql);

        // Ya depende de ti como deseas devolver el resultado ... 
        // return $query->result();
    }

}
```

Comment: Es un proyecto con un monton de query y creo que replicar  a cada query seria un fastidio, espero mas opiniones si no tomare la tuya men :D

Answer (score 0):

Esta bien que crees las dos configuraciones de conexión, solo te falta llamar cada conexión, para lograr esto podrías hacer los siguiente:

Como tienes:

```
$db['default']
$db['nube']
```

Como arrays configuración, para llamar cada conexión debes hacerlo de la forma:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('nube', TRUE);
```

Luego para llamar cada funcion de la DB lo haces de la forma:

```
$DB1->query();
$DB1->result();

$DB2->query();
$DB2->result();
```

Fuente: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html

Comment: Es un proyecto con un monton de query y creo que replicar a cada query seria un fastidio, espero mas opiniones si no tomare la tuya men :D

Comment: Si es demasiado codigo, tambien tienes la alternativa de replicar directamente las bases de datos, solo con el motor de DB en este caso MYSQL